# Modulo settings for successful encryption?

Tags: encryption, discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, terminology

I saw [this awesome video](http://www.wimp.com/howencryption/) which shows how encryption works using "discrete logarithm".

The example says: $3^x\mod17$. I understood that $3$ is called “generator”, because it has no "straight" root and when used with any exponents it walks through entire clock (till $17$ in that case).

1. Would saying $3^x \mod 449825$ make it any weaker, easier to crack, or anything alike? Is there anything I should watch out for when choosing that number?
2. If it's a logarithm, why is it the function having $\mod x$ in it? I have $\log(x)$ on my calculator, not $\mod x$. Is it correct that $\mod x$ stands for modulo?

Comment: 1) yes, 449825 is not a prime. 2) its a discrete logarithm (one in a finite field - in your first example a prime field -  and not in the reals).

Comment: You can emulate mod on a calculator like so: to compute `a mod b`, compute `a/b`, round it down, multiply `b` by the result and subtract `a` from it. E.g. for `77 mod 8`, `77 / 8 = 9.62`, so we have `77 mod 8 = 77 - 8 * 9 = 5`. Or you can just multiply the fractional part by `b`, but you tend to run into precision issues quicker doing it that way.